# Detached HEAD after checking out a branch; how to `push`?

Tags: git, git-detached-head

Here's what I did:

1. Checked out a remote git repository.
2. Added to the `[remote "origin]` section of `.git/config`:

`fetch = +refs/heads/release/BranchName:refs/remotes/origin/release/BranchName`

3. Checked out the corresponding branch:

`git checkout origin/release/BranchName`

After that `git status` reported:

> HEAD detached from origin/release/BranchName

4. Added and checked in some modifications.
5. Tries to `git push`. This resulted in the error message:

> fatal: You are not currently on a branch. To push the history leading
>   to the current (detached HEAD) state now, use
>
> ```
> git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>
> ```

6. Then I followed the suggested command:

`git push origin HEAD:origin/release/BranchName`

and got the following:

> error: unable to push to unqualified destination:
>   origin/release/BranchName The destination refspec neither
>   matches an existing ref on the remote nor begins with refs/, and we
>   are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref. error: failed to
>   push some refs to 'RepositoryName`

Thus the questions: what did I do wrong? How to fix that and push the changes?

Comment: Don't you have a local counterpart for the remote branch you're trying to push on?

Comment: Run `git checkout release/2018/MDP.2018.03` (drop the `origin/` part). With sufficiently recent versions of Git, this will create a _local_ branch that tracks the remote branch of the same name.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The string `origin/release/BranchName` contains both the name of the remote (`origin`) and the remote branch name (`release/BranchName`). The suggested command had these as separate arguments, so you should run:

```
git push origin HEAD:release/BranchName
```

To understand what went wrong, you have to understand that in git, branches don't really exist; a branch is just a convenient pointer to some commit. With a local branch, there are some convenient mechanics for moving that pointer when you commit, but with a *remote* branch, that doesn't happen (because you don't update the remote pointer until you run `push`).

When you ran:

```
git checkout origin/release/BranchName
```

Git looked up a remote branch, found out what commit it pointed to, and checked out that commit. However, it didn't create or update any *local* branch, so when you committed, no new pointer was created, just a bunch of commits. That's what "detached HEAD" means - you have something checked out, but it's not "attached" to any branch.

What you should instead have run was this:

```
git checkout -t origin/release/BranchName
```

Or this:

```
git checkout release/BranchName
```

(Or, in newer versions of git, replace `git checkout` with `git switch` - the functionality is the same in this case, but `git switch` has fewer confusing extra meanings.)

In each case, assuming you don't already have a local branch called `release/BranchName`, git will work out that what you want is a *new local branch* which "tracks" (is associated with for `push` and `pull` commands) the remote branch of the same name.

Then, when you commit, you will be committing to a normal branch, and won't get "detached head" errors.

Comment: Thanks, `git push origin HEAD:release/BranchName` worked.

Comment: @Michael I've just added some more details on how you can avoid getting into the "detached head" state in future. Your best bet right now is to push once from your "detached head", then start again by checking out the remote branch using `checkout -t`

Comment: Thanks, this worked.

Comment: Thanks for this...worked for me. I just wrote push origin command and it worked

Answer (score 0):

In order to push HEAD into a remote branch, the remote branch must exist already. When the branch doesn't exist on the remote end, what I do is push any other branch into the remote branch I want to create and then I push HEAD:

`git push some-remote random-local-branch:remote-branch
git push some-remote -f HEAD:remote-branch`

Or you could just create a local branch temporarily, push it and then remove the branch

`git branch temp
git push some-remote temp:remote-branch
git branch -d temp`